# Creating SSL cert changes document root for all websites and ignores vhosts.conf

Tags: apache, ssl, centos7, vhosts, document-root

Following [this handy guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-centos-7), I was trying to create an SSL certificate for a website. About half-way through I realized I could do the same through CWP, however the process has somehow made all websites show whatever content is located in `/var/www/html` despite every vhosts.conf entry being `DocumentRoot /home/USERNAME/public_html`.

I'm not sure what caused it exactly, but I have since uninstalled the generated certificate and rebuilt the vhosts file and the issue is still persisting.

I'm sure i'm missing something stupid but I'm not sure what.

Comment: what is in `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled` ? If there is no such folder, search some other place for `/sites-enabled`.

Comment: @Andra `sites-enabled` doesn't exist anywhere on the server, but at the same time my other server doesn't even have this file either but works. The only difference is on this server I attempted to add an SSL certificate.

Comment: it's a folder, not a file. I don't have centos,  but still believe there should be such folder for apache.

Comment: I had a couple other people log in and look at some of the .conf files and we as a collective assumed the service was reading some .conf file somewhere we couldn't find. I just wiped and reinstalled the server and have had no issues since.